# Nested comments with Classic ASP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic

The idea behind what I'm trying to achieve is similar to a forum / commenting system I guess. There will be a main topic, then people can reply to that topic and to each other.

As replies are going to be in a completely different order in the database to how they will be displayed the way I thought best to achieve this is to have a parent_id col in the table, parent_id = 0 for a topic message, then replies have the relevant id's for the reply they correspond to.

Then I could use a recursive function to get the data in the right order and display like so e.g.:

Parent Topic

reply

reply

reply to reply

reply

reply to reply

reply to reply to reply

reply

However this is where I am stuck. I'm quite new to VBScript, so it could be something really simple to do, but I just can't see it.

Anyone help it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Why in the world are you writing a new application with classic ASP?

Comment: I do agree with you, but unfortunately this is something I cannot change.

Comment: what exactly are you asking for? Help with the SQL, ASP or both?

Comment: good example code here - easy to setup http://www.asp101.com/resources/aspforum_revisions.asp

Comment: @DOK: Nothing wrong with classic ASP.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you ask for help with the code required to get this from the database?

Here is the code required to show all the "parent" topics:

```
Sub ShowParentTopics()
    Dim strSQL, objRS, objConn
    objConn.Open "connection string here"
    strSQL = "Select * From Topics Where parent_id=0"
    Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
    Do Until objRS.EOF
        Response.Write("Title: " & objRS("Title") & "<br />")
        Response.Write("<a href=""?topic=" & objRS("ID") & """>Expand</a><hr />")
        objRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

And to show specific topic with all its replies you need recursive method, here is one that should work:

```
Sub ShowOneTopic(nTopicID)
    '//validation might be here.... make sure topic ID is numeric!//'
    Call RecursiveShowTopic nTopicID, 0
End Sub

Sub RecursiveShowTopic(nTopicID, nLevel)
    Dim strSQL, objRS, objConn
    Dim x, nChildID
    objConn.Open "connection string here"
    strSQL = "Select * From Topics Where ID=" & nTopicID
    Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
    If Not(objRS.EOF) Then
        For x=1 To nLevel
            Response.Write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
        Next
        If nLevel<1 Then
            Response.Write("Parent ")
        Else  
            Response.Write("Child topic level " & nLevel & " ")
        End If
        Response.Write("Title: " & objRS("Title") & "<br />")
    End If
    objRS.Close

    nChildID = 0
    strSQL = "Select ID From Topics Where parent_id=" & nTopicID
    Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
    If Not(objRS.EOF) Then
        nChildID = CLng(objRS("ID"))
    End If
    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing

    If nChildID>0 Then
        Call RecursiveShowTopic nChildID, nLevel + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Call `ShowOneTopic` with the ID from querystring that will be present when clicking "expand" link on some parent topic.

Of course you'll have to change the connection string, field names and the formatting but this should at least give you something to work with. :)